# How do I enable wifi channels 12-14 when traveling outside the United States?

Tags: wireless, realtek

For whatever reason, the United States' FCC doesn't allow wifi users to broadcast on channels 12-14. However, I'm sure the hardware supports it (RTL8188CE). If I'm traveling outside the United States, is there a way to enable the other wifi channels over 11?

Comment: I'm Australian and I think we're allowed to use 12 and 13 from memory, but many of our devices still default to only using 1 to 11 just in case they're used in the US, I guess.  Remember that you are still using the neighbouring 5 or 11 channels as well (depending on 20/40MHz bandwidth), so using channel 13 you're still overlapping the same frequencies as someone using 11.  IMO enabling those channels doesn't give all that much benefit.  Your base stations would also need to be configured to use those channels too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure, but I think the `CRDA` (Central Regulatory Domain Agent) should change itself based on your localization in system.

To change it manually use:

> % iw reg set `<country code here, e.g. JP>`

Read [this](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory/CRDA) for more info.